# How to change where the file being created when using .open("fileName", "w+") function in Python(VS code environment)?

Tags: python, visual-studio

How can I change where the textfile.txt should be created in VS IDE?

This is the whole structure of the project

```
Learning Python 
>.sfdx
>.vscode
>Debug
>Exercise File
```

The current file I am editing on is somewhere in Exercise File, however when the textile.txt is created by Python, it is located in the folder of Learning Python.

```
Learning Python 
>.sfdx
>.vscode
>Debug
>Exercise File
>textfile.txt
```

Thank you for reading my question, hope it is clear enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the own python to do that, using **getcwd** and **chdir** methods from **os**. The getcwd return the current working directory and chdir is used to change the working directory.

```
import os

current_path = os.getcwd()
print(current_path)

new_path = "/your/path"
os.chdir(new_path)
print(new_path)
```

Comment: Another great way to tackle the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the full path of the file in the open function.

```
f = open(r"C:\Users\deepstop\Documents\textfile.txt", "w+")
```

The r in front of the string is important. It means "raw" and prevents the backslashes in the string from being interpreted as escape characters.

Comment: This is a very helpful way to do as well. I wish I can click to accept both answer. Cheers!

Comment: So kind of semi-private then.